Bootstrap Modal causes useEffect({...}, []) to trigger again
When using the Bootstrap <Modal /> component, when I do callbacks to the parent component, my entrie page rerenders, and triggers my useEffect({...}, [])-Hook, which should only be called once, to be called again, but I do not know why.
My Setup: NextJS, ReactJS, Bootstrap-React
Home() - Parent:
export default function Home() {
  //data and internal logic states, table-content, which rows are selected, is the data still loading, etc.
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [dataZähler, setDataZähler] = useState<ZählerObjekt[]>([]);
  const [dataProtokoll, setDataProtokoll] = useState<ProtokollEintrag[]>([]);
  const [selectedRowZähler, setSelectedRowZähler] = useState(-1);
  const [selectedRowProtokoll, setSelectedRowProtokoll] = useState(-1);
  //View-Logic states, which table is shown, if modals should be seen, etc
  const [showCreateZählerModal, setShowCreateZählerModal] = useState(false);

  //on start, load both csv's into states
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/loadCsv')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setDataZähler(data.dataZähler)
        setDataProtokoll(data.DataProtokoll)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  }, []);

  //rendering logic, the page only needs the data to work, so thats all thats needed, otherwise, show an error and have the user restart
  if (loading) return <p>loading ...</p>
  if (!dataZähler) return <p>No data on counters was found!</p>
  if (!dataProtokoll) return <p>No data on entries was found!</p>

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <table> /* contains data, that gets edited when the modal is used/calls its callback */ </table>
      {/*Modal Div - all edit/Cancel/Save/Create/Delete modals go here*/}
      <div>
        <Modal size="lg" show={showCreateZählerModal} onHide={() => setShowCreateZählerModal(false)}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>
              Neuen Zähler hinzufügen:
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <CreateCounterPopUp data={dataZähler[0]} callback={(data) => {
              if (data)
                setDataZähler([...dataZähler, data]);
              setShowCreateZählerModal(false);
            }} />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

CreateCounterPopUp() - Child:
interface CounterProps {
    data: ZählerObjekt, //seed the PopUp
    callback: ZählerCallback //(only requires a Zählerobjekt)
}

export function CreateCounterPopUp({ data, callback }: CounterProps) {
    const [newCounter, setNewCounter] = useState(new ZählerObjekt());

    function handleSpeichern() { //dont forget to set the id of the new object
        setNewCounter({ ...newCounter, ...{ id: generateGenericObjectID(newCounter) } });
        callback(newCounter);
    }

    function handleInputChange(field: string, event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const newState = { ...newCounter };
        newState[field as keyof ZählerObjekt] = event.target.value;
        setNewCounter(newState);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                {Object.entries(newCounter).slice(1).map((elem, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <Form.Group
                            className="mb-3" key={idx} controlId={elem[0]}
                        >
                            <Form.Label>{elem[0]}</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                as="textarea"
                                rows={2}
                                placeholder={"z.B. " + String(data[elem[0] as keyof ZählerObjekt])}
                                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(elem[0], e as any)} />
                        </Form.Group>
                    );
                })}
                <div className="float-right">
                    <button onClick={handleSpeichern} className="bg-[#22c55e] border-[none] text-[white] text-center inline-block text-base rounded-[5px] px-5 py-3 my-2">Speichern</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

I tried to reduce the size of the page to the most important parts, but can anyone tell me why the modal triggers a full Home() rerender, when the Modal makes use of the callback, but not when its onHide() property is called?

After a bit of testing, it seems that my code completly crashes the renderer and React reloads ... but gives on warning and does not give errors or logs ...

The mistake was that React also calls some other functions in the background, therefore the crash.
function handleSpeichern(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    {...}
}

preventing default events from happening saved the code.
